# RSA and calculating huge exponents

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, cryptography

I am writing an Extended Essay on RSA encryption and in the essay, I am going through a worked example of all of the stages involved (key generation, encrypting and decrypting).

I am using very small numbers, p=47, q=59, n=2773, e=17, ɸ(n)=2668, d=157, which means that I have no problem working out the encryption exponent, my calculator can easily do this, but when I decrypt again, the exponent is 157, which my calculator cannot work out.

What is the best way to perform this calculation? And also if I needed to make the exponent bigger, how would this work? (I would prefer a 'method' rather than a web service, so that I can learn how to do it myself)

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You want to use what is called an infinite precision math library. Most Computer Algebra Systems and tools like Python have these by default. You can also use Wolfram Alpha for those calculations too. Libraries like Crypto++ and LibTomcrypt have these math libraries built-in.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll use them for the time being, I'm interested in finding out how they work behind the scenes though, I tried to do a multiplying loop but this just goes to infinity..

Comment: You can start here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic. You might also consider step-wise modular reductions as you go if you want to do it on a calculator (just reduce at each exponent or group of them).

Comment: No need for arbitrary precision libraries. [Square-and-multiply algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) is your friend. You will never need integers larger than $n^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your links, I'll be sure to take a look! Does this also work for storing the number afterwards? I'm not aware of computers being able to store large numbers to take the modulus of later on.. Maybe I'm wrong

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the exponent $157$, you have $x^{157}=(\cdots(x^2)^2)^2x)^2x)^2x)^2)^2x\,$. So, you don’t need to look at numbers any larger than the square of your modulus, if you reduce after every multiplication.

Comment: But a computer cannot store numbers that big, It stops being accurate (3 s.f) and then says infinity. This then doesn't work when I try to get the answer reduced modulo a short value, it just says 0 (due to the 3 s.f I presume)

Comment: @LlamaGoingNorth Did you take into account the last sentence of Lubin's answer: Reduce modulo $n$ after every multiplication. So you never encounter numbers as big as $n^2$. Surely your computer can handle numbers of that size (smaller than 8 million); a pocket calculator should suffice.

Comment: @AndreasBlass sorry, just saw that now.. Does that mean you would do x = x^2 mod n, then repeat? Could you show me an example (e.g. in pseudocode)? Sorry but I'm teaching myself all of this from scratch, we don't do it in school..

Comment: @LlamaGoingNorth Yes, square x mod n, then square that mod n, then square that mod n, then multiply by the original x mod n, etc. Every time you multiply (either squaring the previous result or multiplying it by the original x), immediately reduce mod n, so that you never multiply two numbers bigger than n, and so you never get a product bigger than n^2.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you so much, makes much more sense now!